# AD extension not listed in MicrosoftGraph, but still available

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to retrieve extension's names and identifiers to old extensions in ActiveDirectory/B2C, the application is still the same, I just access it from Microsoft graph url and authentication instead of the old AD authentication.

There is one extensions for which I know the full name (extension_XXXXX_name), and if I query for that property with a `$select=extension_XXXXX_name` it is retrieved. However if I try to find that extension in all available schemaExtensions, I cannot find "XXXXX"

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions" -H 
 "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" 2>&1 | grep XXXXX
```

What I expect is that Microsoft graph expose a call to query extensions that are not created with the graph API so that I can find out parameters to query in `$select=`.

Actually for XXXXXX I'm lucky because I know it's name, but there are properties with unknown names and I want to find those by inspecting manually `schemaExtensions` result.

However since those old extensions are not included, I cannot find out what their exact names are. I have just access to the API.

Comment: Is this an extension you created at some point? What is the full name of the extension?

Comment: it was created much time ago using AD. I can retrieve it using its full name "extension_XXXXX_name", but it is not displayed in `schemaExtensions` in Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Is it marked as Available?

Comment: It is not listed at all, not Available extensions are still listed in that call, it is just because that extension comes from Azure AD instead of Microsoft Graph that I cannot see it (yet I can still access to its fields with Microsoft Graph)